# How can I inspect html element that disappears from DOM on lost focus?

Tags: python, vue.js, selenium-webdriver, pytest

this is my first post on stack overflow, please let me know what am I doing wrong here: I'm trying to inspect CSS properties from an input into a table cell. The input appears on click and disappears on lost focus, as when I try to inspect it. How can I do it to don't lost focus while I move to another window (the inspector)?

Website: https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/saveSystemUser
Xpath: `userrole_list = (By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="oxd-select-dropdown --positon-bottom"])[1]')`

method:

```
def userrole_li(self):
    return self.driver.find_element(*Admin.userrole_list)
```

main test class

```
from time import sleep
from pageObject.adminpage import Admin
from utilities.baseclass import BaseClass


class Test_admin_suite(BaseClass):

    def test_admin_page(self):
     user = Admin(self.driver)
     ser.admin_page_link().click()
     # Add Button Click
     user.add_button().click()
     # first dropdown click
     user.click_drp().click()
     role =user.userrole_li().text
     print('String Comparison: ',user.userrole_li().text.casefold() == 'Admin'.casefold())

     if role.casefold() == "Admin".casefold():
      user.userrole_li().click()
      print(role)
      sleep(10)
```

```
[webpage inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OFB1.png)

[Xpath,webdriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HzBl.png)
[main test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsiRf.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGSk6.png)

I'm trying to to click on the dropdown element and the element should selected in the dropdown but it's not clickable. Please guide.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to select a option from a dropdown but the dropdown doesn't have any select/option tag or also dropdown is in a flexbox. I am attaching (website inspect) image as a reference.